# UIDocumentInteractionController equivalent for Android Java

Tags: android, dialog, openfiledialog

I would like my android application to display a dialog that allows the user to open a file in another application or save the file much like the `UIDocumentInteractionController` for iOS that displays an "Open in..." dialog for a particular document. Does this not exist in the Android SDK?

[image: UIDocumentInteractionController]

Comment: Android uses Intents/IntentFilters to communicate between apps. Have you seen: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters As for "saving a file", see: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data and read [CommonsWare's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware) blog posts on [the storage situation](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/06/storage-situation-internal-storage.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some trial and error, I managed to find a reasonable solution, but not the equivalent to the iOS `UIDocumentInteractionController`, that uses minimal custom activity code, which just uses an `ACTION_VIEW` intent.:

```java
private void showDialogForFile(File file, String extension) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setType(MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension));
    Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getBaseContext(), 
      getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", file);
    intent.setData(uri);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

I also needed to add the following to my Android manifest:

```xml
<provider 
  android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
  android:exported="false" 
  android:grantUriPermissions="true" 
  android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider">
    <meta-data 
      android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" 
      android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
</provider>
```

And then add to the resource file `res/xml/file_paths.xml`

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="." />
</paths>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Android version of UIDocumentInteractionController is to use the `createChooser` function of `Intent`.  Given a document on your filesystem with a URI of `uri`, do the following:

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
shareIntent.setType("application/pdf"); // or whatever content type it is
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, null));
```

Android documentation is here:

https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send